# iOS Web View with Blurry Text

Tags: ios, text, webview, transform, blurry

I have a web-view with blurry text in iOS 7.  There are many posts with solutions, however none of them seem to work in my case.  The best solution that I've found thus far is to apply `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the blurry elements, as seen [here](https://github.com/01org/appframework/issues/400).  But doing this causes `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to become inoperable.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is the CSS associated with the scrolling wrapper and elements containing blurry text

```
#scrolling_element {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: auto !important;
}

.elements_w_blurry_text {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: url("../path/to/img.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);/* or any other suggested code*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your css:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Still no luck. I've added my css.  Perhaps that will help.